# Garbage collection and property syntax

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a class that needs information from an xml file. I have another class which is constructed to meet that need. Once the information required is in the first class I want the xml reader to be garbage collected.

Now the xml reader gets the information required and stores it in private fields. The first class queries these fields and retrieves the information. I know that if I query the fields using functions provided in the xml reader there will be no residual linkage, will this also be the case if I use properties in the xml reader?

```
public float Var
{
    get { return someVar; }
    set { someVar = value; }
}
```

Comment: Is the XML reader a member variable of the other class? Or is it a local variable in the scope of a member method?

Comment: The XmlReader class is called from within the constructor of the calling class. If I used straight functions to get the variables held in the XmlReader I would be sure that all references to the XmlReader would be lost once the calling class constructor finished. What I do not know is whether property syntax acts to link the variable in the calling class to the variable in the XmlReader... ie, retains a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear your question. You could use the XmlReader in a using if you want to allow that instance to be garbage collected once you process your XML file. Assigning the properties to private variables as you have said sounds correct. GC can collect the XmlReader instance if there are no live references. You could try below [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader).

[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement, defines a scope, outside of which an object or objects will be disposed. It's a good practice to call the Dispose method for objects like XmlReader that have file handlers.

```
   var myProperties;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file1.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
                // myProperties = reader.....;
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code is a good way to check whether there is any issue with garbage collection because it will throw an exception in any case if you try to refer XmlReaders properties out side of the using statement. If you have assigned the values to private variables that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the `XmlReader` (eg, in a field in your class), it cannot be garbage-collected while the owning instance is still alive.

Once you don't have any references to it, it will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I think you are telling me that the property syntax acts like a link, and as such, so long as the variable in the calling class that is filled with the value via property syntax from the XmlReader is alive so too will be the XmlReader.

Comment: @StephenJones: Wrong.  A property is just a method named `get_Var`; it makes no difference to the GC.

Comment: I think we need a definitive answer on this. As far as I understand it property syntax is not simply a method named get_Var, because all methods use the stack and carry overhead which it is the purpose of property syntax to avoid. But the only way I can understand how this would be done is either: a) the compiler just links the variable as it is held in the called class to the calling class, or the compiler takes a copy of the variable and links the calling class to it. Only in the second instance could the called class be let go for garbage collection.

Comment: @StephenJones: You are completely wrong.  Trust me.  If you want further proof, look in ildasm.

Comment: Note that simple getter methods will usually be inlined by the JITter.  The JITter doesn't know about properties; this happens regarldess of what kind of method it is.

Comment: Thank you SLaks. The conclusion to be drawn then, is that if you wish to set more than one value at the same time you are better off to use a single function and pass through all the variables for the one function overhead?

Comment: Completely wrong.  There is no difference between calling one method (or property accessor) and calling two.